# How do I encode something in PHP with a key?

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I see `base64_encode` can encode values, but without a key. I need a function that takes a salt and data, encodes it, and can be decoded with the same salt (but if you try to decode it without the salt, it gives you gibberish).

Is there a PHP function for this (can't find it, only modified versions of `base64_encode`).

EDIT: Found the answer: use [mcrypt ciphers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php)

Comment: By salt and gibberish, do you mean an encryption key and cyphertext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about taking a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: You could generate the key like this; $key = md5(rand()+time()); Ideally you'd improve that algorithm however